# How does std::unique_ptr set the other pointer to null when moving?

Tags: c++, templates, move, unique-ptr, class-template

When a move happens, usually a class sets the `other`'s pointer to null, and this is the case with `std::unique_ptr`. The assignment operator is templated so that you can move `unique_ptr`s to different types (i.e derived classes).

My question is: How can it access the `ptr` in the other class, a `private` member, given that it's an instantiated templated class, and therefore different, and can't access `private` or even `protected` members?

```
template <typename T>
class MyPointer
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void operator=(const MyPointer<U>& other) = delete;

    template <typename U>
    void operator=(MyPointer<U>&& other)
    {
        // WON'T COMPILE, THIS IS A DIFFERENT CLASS FROM THE ARGUMENT
        // CANNOT ACCESS PRIVATE MEMBER 
        other.pointer = nullptr;
        
    }
    char* get() const { return pointer; }

private:
    char* pointer;
};

int main()
{
    struct B {};
    struct D : B {};

    std::unique_ptr<B> base;
    std::unique_ptr<D> derived;

    // std::unique_ptr somehow sets the other pointer to null when moving
    base = std::move(derived);

    MyPointer<B> my_pointer_b;
    MyPointer<D> my_pointer_d;

    // CANNOT ACCESS PRIVATE MEMBER
    my_pointer_b = std::move(my_pointer_d); 
}
```

Comment: `release` and `reset` are both `public`

Comment: not being able to access the private raw pointer is about convenience and correctness, not so much about encapsulating it at all cost, if you want you get it

Comment: It can ask the other part to give up its pointer [`unique_ptr::release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)

Comment: From [this `std::unique_ptr` assignment operator reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D): "Move assignment operator. Transfers ownership from `r` to `*this` as if by calling **`reset(r.release())`**..." (emphasis mine)

Comment: At the very least, `friend` might be a solution too.

Comment: @JeJo I downvoted because of the elephant in the room that is `friend`.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can it access the `ptr` in the other class, a `private` member, given that it's an instantiated templated class, and therefore different, and can't access `private` or even `protected` members?

As others mentioned, you are missing the obvious detail. From the *cppreference.com* the [move assignment `std::unique_ptr::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) explains, how this has been handled for the `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>`(emphasis mine):

> `unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;// (1) (constexpr since C++23)`
>
> [...]
>
> **1**) Move assignment operator. **Transfers ownership from `r` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment of `get_deleter()` from `std::forward<Deleter>(r.get_deleter())`.**
>
> [...]

You could also rework your `MyPointer` the same:

```
template <typename T, typename Deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
class MyPointer
{
public:
    // ... other members

    template <typename U, typename OtherDeleter>
    MyPointer& operator=(MyPointer<U, OtherDeleter>&& other) noexcept
    {
        // Just like the std::unique_ptr does!
        reset(other.release());
        deleter = std::forward<OtherDeleter>(other.get_deleter());
        return *this;
    }

    T* release() noexcept
    {
        T* releasedPtr = pointer;
        pointer = nullptr;
        return releasedPtr;
    }

    void reset(T* newPtr = nullptr) noexcept
    {
        if (pointer != newPtr) 
        {
            deleter(pointer);
            pointer = newPtr;
        }
    }

    template<typename Self> // requires C++23 support !!
    decltype(auto) get_deleter(this Self&& self) noexcept
    {
        return std::forward<Self>(self).deleter;
    }

private:
    T* pointer{ nullptr}; // instead of char* (maybe ?)
    Deleter deleter;
};
```

---

**<sup>†</sup>** Alternatively, you could make the `MyPointer` class be `friend` of the `other`.

```
template <typename T> class MyPointer 
{
public:
    // .... other members!
private:
    T* pointer;

    // Declare MyPointer<T> as a friend of MyPointer<U>
    template <typename U>
    friend class MyPointer;  
};
```

**<sup>†</sup>** This is less recommended, due to the fact, it spoils the idea of encapsulation, and it can be considered as a misuse of `friend` declaration.